# legitimate reopening for a closed as duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

This question: [write json float in scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700585/write-json-float-in-scientific-notation) was closed as a duplicate of [python: json.encoder.FLOAT_REPR changed but no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521823/python-json-encoder-float-repr-changed-but-no-effect)

I have analysed the original question, and it is exactly the same question, so I hammered it (someone else already found the original question, so easy job for me)

Now the answer of the original question doesn't answer the question for a newer version of Python, so OP of the duplicate complained (voted to reopen, and downvoted the answer, even if it works on older versions of python)

I noted down the link so I could post on a Python room to ask for experts if they could add a Python 3.6 compatible answer to the original question. I commented about that so the OP knows that a suitable solution is still looked for.

Checking the question again, I see that some gold badge user [reopened the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50700585/revisions), and an (hack) answer was posted by this same user.

It seems to me that the proper behaviour is to answer the original question, and possibly ping the OP of the duplicate so they can check the answer (and upvote if it works)

Isn't that abusing the reopen feature just to make rep on a duplicate ?

EDIT: seems that there's a better original: [Format floats with standard json module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447287/format-floats-with-standard-json-module) and an answer qualifies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733105/6451573

Comment: AFAIK saying that the answer to a question doesnt work because it is for an older version than what is being used is an appropriate argument for reopening a question. I agree with reopening.

Comment: We mark duplicates for the similarity between the questions, and whether the answer in the duplicate answers the question. If the OP of the potential dupe specified the version of the language/framework/library and the proposed dupe has a different one, then no, they should not be marked as duplicates of one another. In this case, I don't see a version-specific tag on either of them, so I would think it's fair game for closing as a duplicate.

Comment: The question should have been edited to specify what happens when using the version form the duplicate, and why that doesn't work, but had they done so, reopening would have been appropriate.

Comment: I got pinged that I was being talked about here. It was pretty clear that the OP was using Python3, tag or no tag, what with the parens in his `print` statements, and this being 2018 and all. The OP had already posted that the duplicate solution was no longer viable in Py3, and I went to it to reproduce for myself. I found what I thought was a workable alternative that did not require monkeypatching. Is it a hack? I think the current form is pretty solid, since it covers the bases likely to be found in JSON, and uses abc types. But reopening "just to make rep on a duplicate"? I'm no rep whore.

Comment: Now I think that you shouldn't have reopened, but you should have posted an answer in original question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447287/format-floats-with-standard-json-module.

Comment: The problem with posting a new answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447287/format-floats-with-standard-json-module is that it has to compete with a bunch of "dinosaurs": big-scoring answers that mostly only work on Py2, so it'll get buried. Speaking generally, sure, some Py2 answers will give correct results on Py3, but that's not always immediately obvious, and it's unfair to newbies who may be unfamiliar with old behaviour and percent formatting. And of course in some things Py2 code which works may be inefficient compared to the modern way.

Comment: So IMHO if a proposed dupe target is dominated by dinosaurs that don't work properly on Py3 then it should not be used as a target, although it may still be used as a link for Py2 diehards. Let new Py3 answers compete in their own arena!

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Fair point, except that in the old days "python" by default meant Python 2, so no version-specific tag was required. But for the last year or so the trend on SO has been to consider Python 3 as the default, and the regular SO Python community normally doesn't add a version-specific tag to questions that only have the generic tag unless it's required to resolve ambiguity, e.g. on Unicode questions.

Comment: Just to be clear, you didn't end up posting to the python room, did you? Your phrasing here is unclear but if you did I missed it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak no JFF said "to *a* Python room".

Comment: @AndrasDeak no I didn't, since the question got reopened.

Comment: @PM2Ring ... or maybe for duplicates? I'm not part of the Python community, so just a suggestion. 

The problem of "old answers" competing with new ones has historically been solved by editing the answers to include some kind of version information. Thus, those which are obsolete will eventually be overtaken by the newer ones. That's the theory behind Stack Overflow's voting. If that's not working, then SO is not working.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I agree with you. The problem here is that old answers aren't just less performant, they _don't work_ anymore, overtaking will take some time since they have a zillion votes. So I'm changing my mind about this case. But it renders search less performant, since for 1 question there are 2 answers. Stack overflow is known for the relative fast way to find working answers. If users have to test all the answers, that'll be the end of it. Hard to decide...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan We do tend to add version info to significant answers on significant questions, either by editing or commenting, especially those that have been used as dupe targets. If the author's still active we encourage them to update the answer. In some cases, the community has added modern code to obsolete high scoring answers of popular dupe targets, to get around the visibility problem, but in general we prefer to work with the SO voting system, not subvert it like that.

Comment: FWIW, there are currently over 960,000 questions in the generic Python tag, fixing just the important answers to all the old good questions would be a huge undertaking. We have to choose our battles.